# Get number of active class instances

Tags: c++, class

I need to get a number of created and the number of active class instances.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
class Set {
  double value;
  int created = 0;
  int active = 0;
public:
  Set();
  Set(double num);
  static int NumberOfCreated();
  static int NumberOfActive();
};
Set::Set() : value(0) {}
Set::Set(double num) : value(num) {
  created++;
  active++;
}
int Set::NumberOfCreated() { return created; }
int Set::NumberOfActive() { return active; }
int main() {
  Set s1, s2(100);
  { Set s3(50); }                      // After "}", "s3" doesn't exist anymore
  std::cout << Set::NumberOfCreated(); // Should print 3
  std::cout << Set::NumberOfActive();  // Should print 2
  return 0;
}
```

I get two errors:

> invalid use of member ‘Set::created’ in static member function
>
> invalid use of member ‘Set::active’ in static member function

Also, this logic would always give the same output for active and created class instances. Could you give me a better approach to how to find number of active elements?

- Note: `main` function cannot be changed! Only class should be changed to enable this functionality.

Comment: have you heard of destructors?

Comment: Static member functions can only use static member variables.

Comment: yes, but I'm beginner in object oriented programming. How could destructors be used for this?

Comment: How could I use `created++` if it was static? Also, if functions weren't static I couldn't call them with `Set::NumberOfCreated();`

Comment: Presumably you don't want every instance of your class to have its own unique `created` member - but instead want exactly one variable named `created` regardless of how many instances of your class are created.    That can be achieved by making `created` a `static` member of the class.   The constructor and destructor can access `static` members.

Comment: `Set::Set()` is also a constructor. Why does the same logic not apply to objects created using that constructor? In this case the probably best idea would be to add a default value to the parameter of the other constructor and remove the one taking no parameters entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have multiple problems, here is how it can be done, check comments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Set {
  double value;
  static int created; // you need single variable for all instances, this is why static
  static int active;
public:
  Set();
  Set(double num);
  ~Set() {
      --active; // destructor is called when object is destroyed, so number of active instances is decreased
  }
  static int NumberOfCreated();
  static int NumberOfActive();
};

int Set::created = 0;
int Set::active = 0;

Set::Set() : Set(0) {} // this constructor should increase created/active counters as well, this can be achieved via calling another ctor
Set::Set(double num) : value(num) {
  created++;
  active++;
}
int Set::NumberOfCreated() { return created; }
int Set::NumberOfActive() { return active; }

int main() {
  Set s1, s2(100);
  { Set s3(50); }
  std::cout << Set::NumberOfCreated() << std::endl;
  std::cout << Set::NumberOfActive() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and of course follow @user17732522 comments about copy/move and thread safety

Comment: could you explain me why this `int Set::created = 0;`? Why it cannot be done with `static int created = 0;` in the private part of class?

Comment: *"this can be achieved via calling another ctor"* In this scenario my recommendation would be to remove the constructor and add a default parameter to the other one; this way no constructor chaining is necessary.

Comment: @RocketProcd because static variables must be initialized outsize of class, to reserve space for them

Answer (score 3):

You need `created` and `active` to be `static` data members, since they are supposed to describe global state of the program, not individual state of an instance of the class.

Then in every (non-delegating) constructor, including the copy/move constructor which are otherwise defined implicitly and will not count correctly, you will need to increment them. In the destructor you ought to decrement `active` since presumably if an object's lifetime ends you consider it non-active.

Also note that it is possible to end the lifetime of an object without calling its destructor by reusing its storage. Then the `active` counter would not account correctly. That is not something that should happen ordinarily though if the class is used properly.

If there are multiple threads you need to add a mutex as `static` member and lock it prior to any write or read to the two counters or make the counters `std::atomic` variables.

You will also need to add overflow checks and decide what to do when that happens, since overflowing an `int` will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The **problem** is that we can't use non-static data members `created` and `active` from inside `static` member function `Numberof Created` and `NumberOfActive`.

To **solve** this you can make `created` and `active` static and also make use of destructor to decrement `active` as shown below:

```
class Set {
      double value;
      //static data members 
      inline static int created = 0;
      inline static int active = 0;
  public:
      //static member functions 
      static int NumberOfCreated();
      static int NumberOfActive();
public:
  Set();
  Set(double num);
  //declaration for destructor 
  ~Set();
 
};

Set::Set() : value(0) {
    ++created;
    ++active;
    
}
Set::Set(double num) : value(num) {
  created++;
  active++;
}
//implementation for destructor
Set::~Set()
{
    //decrement active 
    --active;
}
int Set::NumberOfCreated() { return created; }
int Set::NumberOfActive() { return active; }
int main() {
  Set s1, s2(100);
  { Set s3(50); }                      
  std::cout << Set::NumberOfCreated()<<std::endl; // print 3
  std::cout << Set::NumberOfActive()<<std::endl;  //prints 2
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is :

```
3
2
```

[Working Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rXK0lROho)